# How to group variables based on custom distance values (no distance function) in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Assume I have 5 variables. Try to cluster them into k groups.

First there will be 10 pairs( # pairs = n(n-1)/2 = 5*4/2=10). For each pair, we calculated a number between 0 and 1 (some sort of similarity, you can think of it as 1-distance). Now we try to put our 5 variables into k groups based on that number. k is a parameter that we can specify, for example 2. Is there any easy way to do that?

I know there are many clustering methods out there. But few takes custom distance function.

Below is an example.

[image: data table]

In this case, Var2, Var3 and Var5 can be in one group (the similarity is 0.93 and 0.92), and Var1 and Var4 in another group.

Try to do this in Python. Anyway, any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I've never done this, but I noticed that `sklearn.neighbors` has a [`DistanceMetric`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) that allows you to set a custom function to return the metric (given two input variables). Perhaps you can start there.

Comment: @Evert. Thanks Evert! I looked it up on sklearn.neighbors and didn't see DistanceMetric allows to set a custom function. I'm new to Python. Can you please point me where you saw that? Any examples on Sklearn if any?

Comment: There's a link in my previous comment.